# I have a boolean that is not setting properly. What is causing this?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, variable-assignment

I have the following code in an Asp.Net user control:

```
Me.pnlAddComment.Visible = MyBase.Associate.IsAgent()
Me.lblRating.Visible = Me.pnlAddComment.Visible
Me.Rating1.Visible = Me.pnlAddComment.Visible
```

Now when I run this code, the value of `MyBase.Associate.IsAgent()` is true. Yet at no point is `Me.pnlAddComment.Visible` evaluating to true. When I output the results as Response.Write statements, it shows IsAgent = True, pnlAddComment.Visible = False. When I run it in debug mode, placing the line break on the second line above to allow the set to occur: I put the mouse over IsAgent and it displays "True"; I put the mouse over pnlAddComment.Visible and it displays "False".

A Co-worker suggested that it's possible that it's `Panel.Visible` black box code in the getter that allows the assignment to occur but returns false because some parent object is set (at that point in the code execution) to False. I've reviewed the parent objects and at no time do any of them appear to be set to not visible.

If this were a reference type I might be convinced that some other process is modifying the reference between this assignment and when it is actually used (at Render), but this is happening right at this line of code.

What would cause this boolean assignment to behave this way without throwing an exception?

**Solution:**
The answer turned out to be a parent object in the control hierarchy located outside of the user control itself. Since nothing was explicitly set to false, and I agreed with @Shadow Wizard, @Damien_The_Unbeliever and @CodeMonkey1 that it had to be some outside control influencing the panel at that point, I decided to put a recursive while loop to test the parent of each user control in the hierarchy at that point:

```
Dim o as Object = Me.pnlAddComment.Parent

While o IsNot Nothing
    Me.lblMessage.Text &= "<br />" & o.ID & ": " & o.Visible.ToString()
    o = o.Parent
End While
```

Then I just ran this on the server and the output came back with the full visibility of each control in the chain. What ended up occurring is that this control was contained within a view control within a MultiView. This view control is expected to be visible as it is supposed to be the ActiveView for this particular call, but at the point in the life cycle when my code is run, the view has not been identified as the active view. Since it's not officially active, the view is implicitly false, and all child controls return a value of false when Visible is queried.

The rest of the assignments behave as expected from that point. The lblRating control is set to false (permanently) because at that moment the proper visibility setting for pnlAddComment is false. The lesson I've learned here is not to make control visibilities dependent on each other in this fashion when there is an alternative (and just as simple) method.

Comment: This can't be explained by .NET behavior, so it must be something with the code of `IsAgent()` method - post it here and we'll see. For example it might "toggle" its return value - first call return `True`, second call return `False` etc.

Comment: @Joel Another idea - if you set the return value to variable first `Dim blnIsAgent As Boolean = MyBase.Associate.IsAgent()` what happens? Anything is different?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: There isn't any real code in it. A username variable is populated by a cookie value. This string is then tested with 2 `Contains` calls separated by an `OrElse`. In any case, it evaluates properly to true. The question is, why doesn't the panel's visible property evaluate to the same given the assignment?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - That was another my co-worker's ideas. We tried it and received the same result. During the entire execution the local boolean remained true, the panel remained false. My co-worker was sufficiently stumped at that point and left my cube saying "Glad it's not my problem."

Comment: @Joel couple of ideas in my sleeve: first use local variable. Second, what happens when you directly `Me.pnlAddComment.Visible = True`?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - Tried the first (see my other comment), second: Tried it, same behavior.

Comment: @Joel shot in the dark..... what's the context of this code? Page, Control or something else? What does the `Me` refer to? What I'm trying to hint is that maybe `pnlAddComment` is not what you think it is.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - It is in a public sub inside a user control. It is called explicitly from the containing page based on query string information. Me refers to the usercontrol which inherits a custom webusercontrol (that holds the Assocate property). These are the first 3 lines of the sub, and the 2 lines following inside the sub populate other areas of the control but do not touch either of these 2 items.

Comment: Off the topic, how you have defined the breakpoint, is it a conditional breakpoint and defined like "Me.pnlAddComment.Visible = False"? Beucase it is an assignment statement and causing value to be changed to False.

Comment: Are we to assume this is a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel`? If so, is `pnlAddComment.Parent.Visible` true also? If not, then it means there's something funny going on when trying to set the Visible property true, rather than when you're trying to retrieve it.

Comment: @ShahidAzim - no it's just a breakpoint in debug. It simply stops execution, and in the VS IDE I can look at the present state of the variables at that moment.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Yes, it is a standard panel, and none of the panel/parent controls above it are set to false at any time (that was my co-worker's idea, and we checked it).

Comment: @Joel - I know you've checked all the call sites, I was wondering if you could check that specific property whilst stopped at the breakpoint. If not, then it's something funny happening when trying to assign the True value. Unfortunately, the code in the setter is a little opaque.

Comment: @Joel maybe the Control itself is hidden? How can you tell non of the parents has it set to False? Anyway, try placing the code in Page_PreRender maybe something along the way is messing with visibility as well..

Comment: @Joe by the way no need to type full name after `@` - three first letters are enough. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I finally found it. It turned out to be a parent object after all, but in a rather sneaky way. I will post an answer or an edit to the accepted answer shortly.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - oh, and I type fast and accurately, so the extra keystrokes don't really cost me anything. Plus old habits die hard. Though I would definitely use that technique if I ran across someone with a name full of x, j, q.

Comment: @Joel fair enough.... also FYI the `@` work only once per comment so Damien didn't get notification for your previous comment, only I got one.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, @Damien_The_Unbeliever - solution posted in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visible getter will return false if any of the control's ancestors are not visible.

Comment: That's generally true, but not guaranteed - it strictly falls back to its Parent's Visible property - if its parent is a custom control which has overridden Visible and doesn't rely on *its* parent, no checks further up the Parent/Child hierarchy will occur.

Comment: this isn't EXACTLY what's going on, but it is exactly what's going on. Do you mind if I edit your answer to provide the ultimate solution?

Comment: @Joel why not edit the original question? Will be more visible IMO.

Answer (score 0):

is the panel that you are using also defining the Visible propery ? it maybe shadowing the Visible property from the base class , meaning the panel has 2 properties. one on the parent and one on the child having different values. i.e. 
myPanel.Visible = False 
myPanel.Base.Visible = True

Answer (score 0):

Check it it has any parent control which is hidden, by pasting some code will make the things more clear. It might be an issue of inheriting parent property... But I am not sure.. until and unless , code is there

Comment: Perhaps you did not read the question fully. I posted the solution as an edit quite some time ago.